# Undefined variable: editor (View: /home/marco/prova/resources/views/home.blade.php)

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a problem, blade not find the variable: editor.
This is the function of my Controller.

```
public function HomeText()
{
    $data = [];
    $data['editor'] = Editore::get();

    return view('home')->with($data);
}
```

And these are the instructions in the file blade.php:

```
<select class="form-control select_editore">

@foreach ($editor as $editore)
  <option>
     {{ $editore->id_editore, $editore->nome_editore }}
  </option>
@endforeach
</select>
```

What is the error?
I hope that you help me!
I'm newbie with Laravel, 
I want to understand where I'm wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Change it to this if you want to use an array:

```
return view('home', $data);
```

If you want to use `->with()`, do this:

```
->with('editor', $data['editor'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
public function HomeText()
{
 $data = [];
 $data['editor'] = Editore::get();
 return view('home')->with($data);
}
```

to this:

```
public function HomeText()
{
 $editor = Editore::all();
 return view('home',compact('editor'));
}
```

and in your blade file
change
`<option>{{ $editore->id_editore, $editore->nome_editore }}</option>`
to
`<option>{{ $editore->id_editore}}, {{$editore->nome_editore }}</option>`

Answer (score 0):

you may want to change the way you pass the variable to this

```
public function HomeText()
{
    $data = [];
    $data['editor'] = Editore::get(); // or all()

    return view('home', $data);
}
```

then you may now use `$editor` in your blade ..

Answer (score -1):

In your way of coding you can’t call `$editor` directly.

You have to use, `$data[‘editor’] as $editore`

```
<select class="form-control select_editore">

@foreach ($data[‘editor’] as $editore)
  <option>
     {{ $editore->id_editore, $editore->nome_editore }}
  </option>
@endforeach
```